# Update div via ajax without layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

In my Zend Framework application I have a div in the sidebar. In the main part I have an accordion list.

How do I update the content of the div via ajax without reloading the whole content while clicking on the accordion list which is generated from the db? How to handle the controller/action statements?

Thank you for any help... Regards

Comment: Are you using any jQuery plugin for accordion or is it Zend Framework feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

[**Zend Framework 1.9 tutorial 13: ZendX_Jquery introduction part 1 - ZendX**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyU3pKkGdII)

and

[**Zend Framework 1.9 tutorial 14: ajax requests part 1 - Accordion Example**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrw8TP62-XU)

Usually in the init method of your controller you need a context switch to enable json

```
$contextSwitch->addActionContext ( 'index', 'json' )->initContext ();
```

In you javascript you  can write your ajax logic and change DOM to apply your new response. Next time be more specific and give us code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select-all-accordion-pieces').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you're clicking on links or something similar
    var dataAboutTheAccordionPieceClicked = $(this).whatever;
    $('select-your-div-here').load('your-controller-url', dataAboutTheAccordionPieceClicked );
});
```

EDIT: the post pointing to the zend framework tutorial is probably better, but this will work in any situation - it's just plain jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you might want to apply logic to the request received in order to return only the necessary little bit of data - do a ajax call to a controller/action.

Get the data in the action.

Return it with:

```
$this->_helper->json($data);
```

That disables the layout and viewrenderer, i.e.:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
echo json_encode(data);
```

Let the javascript handle the data returned.